# My app freeze after upgrading my device to iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I recently upgrade my device to iOS 8.3 from 8.1. my app worked fine on the device while it was set to version 8.1, but now after the upgrade it just freeze.

I debugged and figure out when and why it freezes.
I have 5 array's with capacity of 50 that each contains strings received from different places (ble,gps,video).
when the `NSArray` reaches it capacity i write everything down to a file and remove all objects from the `NSArray`. I have a `UIButton` that when it's pressed i start collecting the data to the `NSArray` and write it to the files ->That's when it freeze!

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

//check if file exisits, if not creates one.
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
//writes and adds data the content to the specifec file.
NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
[fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandler writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandler closeFile];
```

Any ideas why the upgrade version of the device have this affect on my app??

EDIT:
The console log seems to be still running (I have him printing in what function he is at the moment) although the device is frozen.

Comment: What does Console log tell ?

Comment: Have you tried it on the Simulator running iOS 8.3?

Comment: disable `Toggle global breakpoint state` then try to run if any `Exception break point added` generate.

Comment: Is it permanently freezing or have you kept any break point? if not then I guess the issue is happening due to the activity is working in the main thread. Could you please try doing the process in background thread?

Comment: @Raptor I have edit my Q, the log is printing fine and it seems like its still working but the UI is frozen.

Comment: @Ashwin there is no break points, i will try to move the activity to the background thread.

Comment: @Ashwin i feel like kissing you thank you it works great!!

Comment: @GiliAriel u r welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ashwin suggested i moved my activity to the background thread and it works great!